# Outlook .Recipients.ResolveAll ambiguous name resolution failure

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

When resolve all cannot process (due to multiple users on our system with the same first/last name) the macro fails to run. Is there a way to get outlook to display the names and let me select which john doe I want (if not then maybe just remove the names it can't resolve).

```
    Sub Reply_All_From_Folder()

    Dim original As MailItem

    Dim reply As MailItem

    Set original = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.ReplyAll

    Set reply = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With reply

        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "folder@work.com"

        .Subject = original.Subject

        .To = Replace(original.To, "emailoRemove@test.com", "")

        .CC = original.CC

        .HTMLBody = original.HTMLBody

        .Recipients.ResolveAll

        .Display

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Cannot recreate "fail to run". Mail displays with unresolved names after which you can "Check Names".

Comment: @niton I am not sure what you mean. When the names cannot resolve I get an error on line ".send"

Comment: The code in the question has .Display.  When you ask a question do not use uninformative "fail to run" type phrases. Specify the line with the error and the associated text.

Comment: Don't use *`,`* use *`;`* Example `.To = Replace(original.To; "emailoRemove@test.com")`

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate pressing the Check Names button if ResolveAll is false.

```
Sub Reply_All_From_Folder_NotResolveAll()

    Dim trueoriginal As mailItem
    Dim original As mailItem
    Dim reply As mailItem

    Set trueoriginal = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    Set original = ActiveInspector.currentItem.ReplyAll
    Set reply = CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With reply

        .subject = original.subject
        .To = original.To & "; notaresolvablename" & "; smith, john"

        If Not .Recipients.ResolveAll Then
            .Display
            ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("CheckNames")
        Else
            .Send
        End If

    End With

trueoriginal.Close olDiscard

ExitRoutine:
    Set trueoriginal = Nothing
    Set original = Nothing
    Set reply = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The "if not" worked perfectly and displayed check names.